# Need help with this transformer circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, homework

I need some help with this circuit. I have simplified it in three steps.
The task is to find the current \$I\$. The values to \$e(t)\$, \$Z1\$, \$Z2\$, \$Z3\$, \$Z4\$, and the turn ratio \$N1/N2\$ are known. I'm not quite sure if I have even done the transformer conversion correctly. But my main question is the current \$I\$.

\$Z4 = Z1 + Z3\$

[image]

Comment: @relayman357 Stop _answering_ questions in the comment section.

Comment: @relayman357, it's `\$` for MathJAX on EE.SE.

Comment: @Transistor  Thank you sir. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good so far. Now solve for primary current E/Z4 and then find the secondary current, I, by [turns ratio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer).

Remember that current reference arrow going into polarity dot on primary means current arrow out of dot on secondary. In other words, draw your primary current reference arrow coming up and out of your voltage source - this current will be in phase with I as you have assigned it’s arrow in your picture.